# Is there a way to join strings, each with a specific surrounding string?

Tags: java, string, guava

I'm looking to use guava's `Joiner` to join `List<String>` into one string, but with surrounding strings around each one in the list. So I want to take a list of Strings:

```
List<String> names = Arrays.asList("John", "Mary", "Henry");
```

and generate this one string:

```
"your guest John is here, your guest Mary is here, your guest Henry is here"
```

The examples I see of using `Joiner` seem to be to generate the 3 names separated by a comma, but I'm looking to surround each string with some extra strings (the same ones every time).

I hope I'm being clear enough here. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You cannot do this with only `Joiner`. `Joiner` puts things between elements, not around them.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20945602/guava-joiner-doesnt-have-ability-to-prefix-and-suffix more details explanation available.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The way to do this is with a transform, first:

```
 Joiner.on(", ").join(Iterables.transform(names, new Function<String, String>() {
   public String apply(String str) { return "your guest " + str + " is here"; }
 }));
```

Comment: F* yeah, functional programming!

Comment: And with Java 8, `names.stream().map(name -> "your guest " + name + " is here").collect(Collectors.joining(", ")`.

Answer (score 4):

How about

```
    String str = "your guest " + Joiner.on(" is here, your guest ").join(names) + " is here";
```

Comment: My guess would be that Natix refers to the fact that part of the text is hardcoded twice

Answer (score 0):

if Joiner is not a must you can use `String.format()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> names = Arrays.asList("John", "Mary", "Henry");
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        for(int i=0; i<names.size();i++){
            builder.append(String.format("your guest %s is here, ", names.get(i)));
        }
        System.out.println(builder.substring(0,builder.length()-2).toString());
    }
```

Comment: Whole point of `Joiner` is to avoid such solutions so +0. Also you shouldn't concatenate `result` in loop, but `append` its new parts to `StringBuilder`.