# Guava Joiner doesn't have ability to prefix and suffix

Tags: java, google-api, guava

I have requirement in Joiner to have the ability to prefix and suffix elements.

For example

```
String str[] = {"a", "b", "c"};
Joiner.on(",").prefix("'").suffix("'").join(str);
```

---

Expected output would be:

```
'a','b','c'
```

Do we have any alternative for this? As Guava doesn't do it (or I'm not aware of). With java 8 is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use Guava's `List#transform` to make the transformation `a --> 'a'` and then use `Joiner` on the transformed list. `transform` only works on `Iterable` objects, though, not on arrays. The code will still be succinct enough:

```
List<String> strList = Lists.newArraylist(str); // where str is your String[]
Joiner.on(',').join(Lists.transform(str, surroundWithSingleQuotes));
```

where the transformation is as follows:

```
Function<String, String> surroundWithSingleQuotes = new Function<String, String>() {
    public String apply(String string) {
        return "'" + string + "'";
    }
};
```

One might say this is a long-winded way of doing this, but I admire the amount of flexibility provided by the `transform` paradigm.

**Edit (because now there's Java 8)**

In Java 8, all this can be done in a single line using the [Stream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) interface, as follows:

```
strList.stream().map(s -> "'" + s + "'").collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

Comment: i like it. the accepted answer falls apart because it's not a true decorator; for example, if you want different surrounding strings depending on some condition, the transform() approach would be more direct

Comment: accepting this answer.

Comment: @MohdAdnan : if you are starting with an array instead of a list, you can directly use `Arrays.stream(str_array)` instead of converting it to a list first. The remaining `map` and `collect` steps remain the same.

Answer (score 9):

A more efficient solution is

```
String str[] = {"a", "b", "c"}; // or whatever
if (str.length == 0 ) {
    return "";
}
return "'" + Joiner.on("','").join(str) + "'";
```

which is also shorter than using a Function (at least without function literals; the handling of an empty input makes this solution ugly). The bad part is the fact that you have to include the prefix and suffix in the `Joiner` in an not really obvious way and repeat them. This example makes it more obvious:

```
return "[" + Joiner.on("], [").join(str) + "]";
```

To get it right without thinking, just remember what comes out for `["+", "+"]`, namely `[+], [+]` and use the plus-separated parts.

Comment: This approch will work well except u have have empty array to join. So probably we need to handle if array is empty do not join them. I just added that if check.