# How can I use Joiner, to join only specific properties?

Tags: java, guava, joiner

Let's say I have this class:

```
public class MyClass {
    private String propertyOne;
    private String propertyTwo;
    // getters setters...
}
```

Now, in my test method, I am trying something like:

```
List<MyClass> myList = myListDao.findAll(); 
String aStringFullOfPropertyOnesOfAllMyObjects =  Joiner.on(", ").join(myList.iterator());
```

The `String`, I want to get back is something like:

```
"propOneOfObjectOne, propOneOfObjectTwo, propOneOfObjectThree"
```

How can I do this?

Comment: why not build the string yourself?

Comment: @meskobalazs I am trying to keep it simple and learn.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to join strings, each with a specific surrounding string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20203594/is-there-a-way-to-join-strings-each-with-a-specific-surrounding-string)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**The "old-school" solution:**

You could use the built-in standard StringBuilder:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
Iterator<MyClass> iter = myList.iterator();
for (MyClass object = iter.next(); iter.hasNext();) {
    builder.append(object.getPropertyOne());
    if (iter.hasNext()) {
         builder.append(", ");    
    }
}
String result = builder.toString();
```

**Using Joiner:**

Using `Joiner` from the linked answer:

```
Joiner.on(", ").join(Iterables.transform(myList, new Function<MyClass, String>() {
    public String apply(MyClass object) { return object.getPropertyOne(); }
}));
```

Comment: Are you sure this is right? It does not compile. (Using Joiner)

Comment: I haven't tested the code, as I don't use this library. What is the error?

Comment: The apply method requires a parameter of type String, not MyClass.